# Zend framework issue in tranfer from one server to another

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-db, zend-studio

I have transfer zend framework from one server to another.
its working fine but Auth controller is not working. it got error page not found issue, while a user login. Even it login the user but redirect on page not found. I am not sure where I need to make changes. Is it server issue or configuration issue as it work fine in my other server.

mod_rewrite of apache is enabled, server is pointed to public with .htaccess

**.htaccess file**

```
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development      
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

**application.ini**

```
        includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
        bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
        bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
        appnamespace = "Application"
        resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
        resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
        resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
        resources.layout.layout = "default"

        [staging : production]
        phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
        phpSettings.display_errors = 1

        [testing : production]
        phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
        phpSettings.display_errors = 1

        [development : production]
        phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
        phpSettings.display_errors = 1
        resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

        database.host = "localhost"
        database.username = "xxx"
        database.password = 'xxxxxx'
        database.dbname = "xxx"

        autoloadernamespaces[] = "Resources_"
        autoloadernamespaces[] = "Plugins"
        resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Plugins_ViewSetup"
```

**index.php in public folder**

```
        defined('BASE_URL')
                    || define('BASE_URL', 'http://11.11.11.11'); // Live

        defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
                || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

        defined('CHARTS_FONT_PATH')
                || define('CHARTS_FONT_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../library/Charts/fonts'));

        defined('PUBLIC_FOLDER')
                || define('PUBLIC_FOLDER', 'public');

        defined('DATA_UPLOAD_PATH')
                || define('DATA_UPLOAD_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/data'));

        // Define application environment
        defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
                || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

        // Ensure library/ is on include_path
        set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
                    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
                    get_include_path(),
                )));

        /** Zend_Application */
        require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

        /** Utilities */
        require_once 'Utils.php';

        // Create application, bootstrap, and run
        $application = new Zend_Application(
                        APPLICATION_ENV,
                        APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
        );


        $application->bootstrap()
                ->run();
```

Comment: I think we need additional info about the Auth controller on which you appear to be getting the 404. Specifically: controller class name, filesystem path to the controller, any additional routing you have defined, any in-code redirects to the auth controller.

Comment: Also, I might be misunderstanding. If the auth controller is successfully logging in the user, then perhaps it is the page to which the auth controller is redirecting which is not being found. Please provide the line in the auth controller that performs that redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issue in database view access issue. I just debug code and check the error. Fixed